# Entity Framework 5 multiple databases, single context

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-5

I have 2 different SQL Server databases which cannot be combined as one of them is a vendor db. Aside from creating a view in SQL server with linked databases, is there a way to use fluent api or something in entity framework to perform simple joins between tables between the two databases?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this will is how its done.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/how-to-join-two-tables-from-different-database-using-entity/